# Append row in pandas dataframe doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I'm really new to Python, and I'm trying to implement Naive Bayes without Machine Learning package, however I have trouble in dataframe handling

```
trained.append({'a':[0,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]},ignore_index=True)
print(trained)
```

`trained` is a DataFrame which index is `name` (str)
the process can be run without error
but the output is just a Empty DataFrame

I also tried

```
trained.loc['label1']=each_row.iloc[0,:]
/*...*/
trained.loc['label2']=each_row.iloc[0,:]
print(trained)
```

each_row is a dataframe with only one row, something like `{'a':[0,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]}`
but the output is a (1,12) dataframe, not expected (2,12)

```
trained.append(each_row)
```

also don't work

please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to assign the appended df to df?

```py
trained = trained.append({'a':[0,5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]},ignore_index=True) 
print(trained)
```

Comment: Oh my god I made a super dummy mistake! The append examples I saw are all called in python shell. I think that's why I didn't notice I have to assign. Thank you!